# Why does Array(x).join populate x-1 results? In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Eg.`Array(5).join(" 5");`

Prints:
`5 5 5 5`

Thanks! I am a JS n00b

Answer (score 3):

The argument to "join" is the separator used between elements. The array, as declared, has five elements; so, in effect, you're inserting four " 5" "separators" between five blank array elements, hence the result you're observing.

Answer (score 1):

It's not.

```
Array("1", "2").join("x")
"1x2"
```

You have `Array(5)` which is actually:

```
Array(5)
[undefined × 5]
```

And joining with " 5"

so you have `{undefined} 5{undefined} 5{undefined} 5{undefined} 5{undefined}`

Undefined prints nothing.  So you get:

`5 5 5 5`

Answer (score 1):

Try a different join character:

```
Array(5).join('a5');

    a5 a5 a5 a5
   0  1  2  3  4
```

You have have 5 elements, but since they're EMPTY elements, you never see the `0` position.

or better yet:

```
 ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'].join('a')

 xaxaxaxax
 0 1 2 3 4
```